# Why do some Applications use a "fat-jar" compared to a normal one?

Tags: maven, sbt, sbt-assembly

What is the advantage of using a fat-jar over a traditional jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fat Jar is just a packaging that includes all application dependencies inside the jar file it self, So for example: if your application A belongs to commons-codec-xyz.jar then fat jar's packaging would be like

```
A-fat.jar
-
|
|-your.app.A.class
|-your.app.B.class
|-org.apache.commons.codec.Foo.class
```

This way if your app jar is expected to be part of some body else's app's classpath then it makes it **really** hard to avoid conflicts at runtime

It is just a cheaper way of managing classpath so when you launch your app you don't have to deal with providing classpath entries you could just do it

```
java -cp .:/path/to/A-fat.jar your.Main
```

Better packaging are to assemble jars into certain compressed format (.zip, .tar.gz, etc..) that holds following structure

```
A.jar
|
|--lib/
    |
    |-A.jar (only A's classes)
    |-common-codec-xyz.jar
```

this way it stays transparent what goes into classpath also you could control order of classpath, but you could not distribute it as library which some body else could re-use in their app, for that purpose you should use maven dependencies that would take care of transitive dependencies

It all depends on application but these are general thoughts

Comment: So I in a distributed system like Hadoop, If i'm using a fat jar, then dependencies wouldn't need to be added to the classPath?

Comment: if your fat-jar covers all your third party dependencies inside the single jar then you don't need to add another classpath entries for those